# cucumber / rails error uninitialized constant DatabaseCleaner (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, integration-testing, capybara

Anyone have any idea what is causing this error when running `cucumber features`?

```
uninitialized constant DatabaseCleaner (NameError)
```

Comment: Do you have the database_cleaner gem installed (and in your gemfile if using rails3?)

Comment: No, I don't. I've never had to specify it in my gemfile...

Comment: Adding it does fix the problem - although it would be interesting to know what's causing it. The default format is also now `pretty`, which I've never had before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DatabaseCleaner is a library for 'cleaning' your db.  Cucumber will use it between running features to ensure your db is in a testable state (ie. empty).

The idea is that you build up the proper data in your `Given` clauses for each test

This error just means that DatabaseCleaner hasn't been required properly.

Different versions of Rails/Cucumber have different ways of configuring everything and provide different functionality with this regard so it's hard to actually give you the right solution without knowing your setup.

A couple of tips though:

Look at the [cucumber-rails](https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber-rails) gem.  It gives you lots of nice stuff such as generators and also rake tasks so you can run `rake cucumber` instead of using cucumber directly.  Often times the generators will build a config file that requires `database_cleaner` for you.

Otherwise, add `database_cleaner` to your list of dependencies and put a `require 'database_cleaner'` somewhere in your test suite code.

Comment: i had webrat in my gemfile when i ran `rails g cucumber:install`, and i later switched to capybara...perhaps this has something to do with it?

Comment: This answer is overly long and doesn't answer the question at all. "list of dependencies"? How does a newbie know what that is? Be explicit.

Comment: no the headless browser you're using shouldn't matter...  if you've already done the `cucumber:install`, trying testing it with the rake task rather than by using `cucumber` directly, it might set up the additional dependencies: https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/Using-Rake

Answer (score 16):

Add this line to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'database_cleaner'
```

This is because `cucumber-rails` doesn't automatically depend on `database_cleaner` because you may be building a Rails application without a database, and so you must explicitly require it.

Comment: I've also added ``require 'database_cleaner'`` to ``spec_helper.rb`` to handle this exception.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced the problem. I downgraded my cucumber gems to version 1.0.6, and I got this message:

```
uninitialized constant Cucumber::Rails::Database (NameError)
```

when I use cucumber 1.0.6 (not the latest version) and database_cleaner v. 1.7.0. For fixing the error, I just run this command (on Rails 3.1.3):

```
rails g cucumber:install
```

It will prompt you to replace file `features/support/env.rb`. Just answer with `Y` and you can run `rake cucumber:ok` again.

Answer (score 0):

I am using spring, and `spring stop` work for me